openai,embeddings-utils import for openai 1.2.0 version
#from openai.embeddings_utils import get_embedding, get_embeddings, cosine_similarity
what will be import for version 1.2.0, as the given import is for version 0.27.6
I am expecting the new import for openai version 1.2.0
